# Jenkins, build execute shell, change shell running user on ubuntu

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to setting up Jenkins on my Ubuntu server.

```
$ sudo -u otherUser /bin/bash
$ whoami                  # I expected "otherUser" but show "jenkins"
$ start_build_script.sh   # This file will clones multiple remote repository
```

But when git cloning, its process will be failed because it clone with "jenkins" user.

```
jenkins@repo.com: Permission denied (publickey).
# The public key (for "otherUser") is already added to repo.com
# I want to clone as otherUser@repo.com
```

I know why this error is happened, but unfortunately I cannot add "jenkins" user to the repository site. So I must use "otherUser" user.

I can modify files only in my ubuntu server, but I cannot modify anything on remote repository.

How can I change user to others when running build script, instead of "jenkins"?

Comment: No enough details,but you can set up the controller/master as one user, the egannode as another and the use credentials in the clone as another user. Why are you wrapping it all in another shell script?

Comment: Because I want to other user cannot configure anything using Jenkins system, and all build related scripts will be managed by git.

Comment: Odd. Nevertheless, if it's all in git, then why not use a [pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) and Jenkinsfile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) instead of a shell step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change JENKINS_USER in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` where all jenkins related information present.

Then shell command will run with that user on your master.

If running on agent then you can configure by which user agent should be connected.

---

As of the latest version, the above changes need to be made in "/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins"

---

Comment: Thanks. I found `/etc/default/jenkins` configuration file and change JENKINS_USER value to other value, and works.